# list.append() in loops can only return final list

Tags: python, list, loops, append

For example:

```
a = {}; 
b = [];
for i in range(20):
    b.append(i)
    a[i] = b
```

After loops, all keys of a is linked to the same final list `b [0,1,2,...,19]`.
However, what I want is that `a[0] = [0]`, `a[1] = [0,1]`, `a[2] = [0,1,2]`.
I have no idea what is wrong here.

Comment: `a[i] = b` you keep setting the value of your dict at i to *the same list* `b`, use `b.copy()` instead to get a copy...

Comment: @juanpa Make that an answer.

Comment: you fall into copy a list issue in python , actually all list you assign into `a[i]` are all have same ids (try with `id(Object)`) so changing `b` will change the previous `a[i]`s , try to copy list `b` to `a[i]` with `copy.copy` method.

Comment: @AubreydaCunha no, this is a duplicate. This same issue pops up many times every day in the python tag

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I didn't notice this before.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {}; 
b = [];
for i in range(20):
    b=[k for k in range(i)]
    a[i] = b
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `[k for k in range(i)]`  should probably just be `list(range(i))`. Also, this doesn't really explain to the OP what is wrong, or what you answer is doing to fix it.